# Session data persists after session_unset and session_destroy

Tags: php, session

I have a contact form, `contact.php`, which is processed in `form-processing.php`.

The form fields are stored in the session array (including ant validation errors) and `form-processing.php` redirects back to `contact.php` on error or success.

On success, a thank you message is displayed (instead of the form) on `contact.php` and the session is deleted using `session_unset()` followed by `session_destroy()`. The blank form should then display again on refreshing the page (since the session array will be empty).

However, the data in the session persists even after being `unset` and `destroyed`. How can this be? I've confirmed the session is deleted by performing a `var_dump` before and after the `session_unset(); session_destroy();` on the `contact.php` page. So, after the first time completing form, the thank you message is always displayed.

`contact.php`:

```
session_start();

if ( $_SESSION['success'] ) {
    // display thank you message
    session_unset();
    session_destroy();
} else {
    //display form
}
```

`form-processing.php`:

```
session_start();

//get $_POST array, validate, sanitize and save to $_SESSION

//send form contents by email

if ($email_sent) {
     $_SESSION['success'] = true;
}

// redirect to contact.php
```

**Edited to update**

This is on a Wordpress installation and there was some issue with where the session was being started. I moved `session_start()` out of the template file and in to a conditional function in `functions.php` and the form now works.

Comment: What is $email_sent?

Answer (score 0):

This should completely destroy the session:

```
session_unset();
session_destroy();
session_write_close();
session_regenerate_id(true);
if (isset($_COOKIE[session_name()])) {
    setcookie(session_name(), '', time()-42000, '/');
}
```

You can also do:

```
$_SESSION = [];
```

Comment: Thanks, but this simply doesn't work (in this case) - I can perform a `var_dump` after using your code above to confirm that the session is "empty" only for it to be "regenerated" with the original data on page refresh.

Comment: Also clear the cookie before running session_destroy() :     if (isset($_COOKIE[session_name()])) {
        setcookie(session_name(), '', time()-42000, '/');
    }